# Can I use react-native-maps for distance calculation between two coordinates?

Tags: react-native, maps, coordinates, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps but I wanna know if its possible to measure the distance between two coordinates (in road not air distance).

I know I can use Haversien package but this calculates the air distance.

Answer (score 0):

The google maps distance matrix service could be used for this purpose. The service "computes travel distance and journey duration between multiple origins and destinations using a given mode of travel". Here is a link to the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix.